# Visualforce Page List output

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, force.com

How do you print out a custom Apex class list, that is not related to an Sobject?  I keep getting error of 
Error: Unknown property 'apiMyIntegrationCom.customerScorecardDiscountDetail.discountCategory'

Most code cut out for simplicity.  I know the data is there, cause if i just use {!DiscountDetails} in visualforcepage, the data comes out for the whole class,var names and everything.  Just looking to get particular vars.

```
public class MyController{

private apiMyIntegrationCom.customerScorecardResponse custScoreCard;

  ......
  public apiMyIntegrationCom.customerScorecardDiscountDetail[] getDiscountDetails(){

    return this.custScoreCard.discountDetails;
  }

}
```

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="MyController"> 
<table id="discountTable">
<apex:repeat id="dd" value="{!DiscountDetails}" var="dds">
<tr>

<td>{!dds.discountCategory}</td>
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `getDiscountCategory()` to your `apiMyIntegrationCom.customerScorecardDiscountDetail` class (and any other fields you wish to expose on VF)

VF needs either explicit `getProperty(), setProperty()` methods or this notation: `public String property {get; private set;}`. Some more info can be found in my other answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9171/799

It looks like your class is autogenerated from WSDL file? Yep, that means you need to modify this code by sprinkling getters everywhere and you'll have to repeat this process every time you regenerate the class...

Comment: Thank you very much!
We assumed the WSDL generation would have set this all up for this, so we never checked there, thought it was with our custom controller and page.  
Thank you very much!